# Showing uniform convergence of a sequence of functions which are inherited from a different function

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, uniform-convergence, uniform-continuity

> Let $f: \Bbb R \times [0,1] \to \Bbb R$ be a continuous function and $(x_n)$ be a sequence in $\Bbb R$ that converges to $x$ in $\Bbb R$.
>   Then show that the sequence of functions $g_n$ defined by,$$g_n(y)=f(x_n,y) \;\;\;\; 0 \le y \le 1$$
>
> $$g(y)=f(x,y) \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; 0 \le y \le 1$$
>
> is uniformly convergent to $g$.

**My attempt :**

Since the set $\{x_n\}_{n \in \Bbb N} \times [0,1]$ is closed and bounded, it is  compact. Hence $f$ is uniformly continuous on $\{x_n\}_{n \in \Bbb N} \times [0,1]$.

Consider the sequence $((x_n,y))_{n \in \Bbb N}$ for an arbitrary $y \in [0,1]$. It converges to the point $(x,y)$. Therefore, for a given $\epsilon \gt 0$, $\exists \delta(\epsilon) \gt 0$ and $n_0(\delta(\epsilon))=n_0(\epsilon) \in \Bbb N$ such that for all $y \in \Bbb [0,1]$ and $\;\forall n \ge n_0(\epsilon)$,

$||(x_n,y)-(x,y)|| \lt \delta(\epsilon) \Rightarrow |f(x_n,y)-f(x,y)| \lt \epsilon \Rightarrow |g_n(y)-g(y)| \lt \epsilon.$

Note that $n_0(\epsilon)$ and $\delta(\epsilon)$ depend only on $\epsilon$.

(I have tried to combine sequential continuity and uniform continuity of $f$ in the above proof)

Have I done it right? Are there any loopholes in this proof?
Thanks.

Comment: It is fine. Just one little thing: $(\{x_n\}_{n \in \Bbb N}\cup \{x\}) \times [0,1]$ is compact.

Comment: @RobertZ Yes yes. I forgot taking Union with $x$. +1

Comment: @RobertZ I think one more minor thing that I should've mentioned is that $n_0$ depends on $\epsilon$ as well as $x$. This won't make any difference in the proof though. Do you agree?

Comment: I agree. Here $n_0$ does not depend on $y$.